# /tmp/cctXTBVn.ltrans0.ltrans.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN2cv3MatC1ERKS0_RKNS_5Rect_IiEE'

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to compile and test a C++ library, but get an error when compiling :

/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cctXTBVn.ltrans0.ltrans.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN2cv3MatC1ERKS0_RKNS_5Rect_IiEE'
//home/ahmet/Downloads/opencv-4.1.2/build/lib/libopencv_core.so.4.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
Makefile:345: recipe for target 'bin/aRecognizer-cu+dbg' failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bin/aRecognizer-cu+dbg] Error 1

- opencv=4.1.2.
- The kit= Desktop Qt 5.13.1 GCC 64bit
- Ubuntu 18.4

I am beginner. any clues would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems you don't *link* with the OpenCV library itself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are right, I have realized that I don't link some of library